# Receive List<Object> in android studio and SignalR

Tags: java, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

i'm working with Asp Mvc, SignalR and Android Studio(with signalr java cliente), right now everythings work great in both side.

I can send and Receive simples objects using signalr from my android app, but now i want to receive a list of object but i dont know how to do it, this is my code:

```
//Both side Android Client and Server, when i send a category to android works. 
public class Category

{
  private int Id;
  private String Name;

  getters...
  setters..
}
```

in my Hub (asp .net mvc 5), i have this method:

```
public void Categories()
{
   var categories = contexto.Categories.ToList()
   hubContext.Clients.All.getCategories(categories);
}
```

When i send just use Category it's works. like this:

```
//THIS WORKS


hubProxy.on("getCategory", new SubscriptionHandler1<Category>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final Category category) {
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                          //....
                        }
                    });
                }
            },Categories.class);
```

But i want to use List, something like:

```
hubProxy.on("getCategories", new SubscriptionHandler1<List<Categories>>() {
            @Override
            public void run(final List<Categories> categories) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      //....
                    }
                });
            }
        },List<Categories.class>); //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved my same issue before by using `Categories[].class` instead of `List<Categories.class>`.

Of course, then you can convert the array to the list.

Hope this helps!